# is the maximal tensor product of compact operators an essential ideal?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, tensor-products, counterexamples

I'm searching for a counterexample for $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ and essential ideals (I assume an ideal to be closed and only two-sided ideals) $I\subseteq A$, $J\subseteq B$ , such that the ideal $I\otimes_{max} J$ is not essential in the (maximal tensor product) -$C^*$-algebra  $A\otimes_{max} B$. I'm not sure if my idea works:

The algebra of compact operators $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ is an essential ideal in the $C^*$-algebra of bounded linear operators on  $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$. The reason is that $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ has only the closed ideals $\{0\}$, $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ and $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$, thus $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\cap M\neq 0$ for all closed nontrivial ideals $M\subseteq B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$.

But is $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ essential in $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$?

I don't think so, but I'm stuck to prove that there must be a nontrivial closed ideal $M$ in $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ such that $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\cap M$ is trivial. For the proof it must be important that one takes the maximal norm-closure of $I\odot J\subseteq A\odot B$ ($\odot$ denotes the tensor product as $*$-algebras), because particularly the spatial tensor product satisfies that if $I$ is essential in $A$, $J$ essential in $B$, then $I\otimes_{min} J$ is essential in $A\otimes_{min} B$ (and here  is $B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{min} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\neq B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$. If my ideal don't work, what else can I do?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your example works. Since you seem to have almost all the elements to show this, I'll only suggest using that  if $I$ is an essential ideal in a C*-algebra $A$ then $\|a\|=\sup \{\|ax\|\mid x\in I,\|x\|\leq 1\}$ for all $a\in A$. Use also that on $\mathcal K\otimes \mathcal K$ the min and max norms agree.

Comment: thanks! I got it. Your hint to use that $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ is nuclear is very helpful.

Comment: Hey Sabrina :D *waving*

Comment: At first, why does $K(\ell^2)\otimes_\text{max}K(\ell^2)$ **embed** into $B(\ell^2)\otimes_\text{max}B(\ell^2)$? As far as I know, this property is quite special for the **spatial** C*-norm, i.e. restriction of a spatial C*-norm is again spatial and as such the spatial tensor product of subalgebras always **embeds**. If I'm not mistaken, this is not the case for the **maximal** C*-norm. That would be an issue in your answer below, too.

Comment: @FreeziiS Hi! See here https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/wwinter/wwinter/operatoralgebren_II_files/blatt04.pdf nr. 2. The proof works like that: If I is an ideal in a $C^*$-algebra $A$, $J$ an ideal in a  $C^*$-algebra $B$, denoting with $\iota:I\odot J\to A \odot B$, $\iota(\sum i_k\otimes j_k)=\sum i_k\otimes j_k$ the inclusion map on the *-algebraic tensor product

Comment: this linear map is injective on the *-algebraic tensor product, such that one can view $I\odot J$ as a subspace of $A\odot B$. Furthermore, $I\odot J$ satisfies the ideal property in  $A\odot B$: If $x\in I\odot J$ and $y\in A\odot B$, then $xy,yx\in I\odot J$. Now, let $\gamma$ be an arbritrary $C^*$-norm on $A\odot B$, $\iota$ is isometric as a map on the *-algebraic tensor product with respect to $\gamma$, so that $\iota$ extends  to an isometry $I\otimes_{\gamma} J\to A\otimes_{\gamma} B$.

Comment: Therefore, $I\otimes_{\gamma} J$ is a $\gamma$-closed subspace of $A\otimes_{\gamma} B$ and one can check that this subspace satisfies the ideal-property as well.

Comment: @SabrinaGemsa: Sure, the $^*$-algebraic tensor product of more generally sub-$C^*$-algebras, is again a sub-$C^*$-algebra. Then restricting a $C^*$-norm to the $^*$-algebra results in sub-$C^*$-algebra. BUT, the issue is that the restriction of a "universally" defined $C^*$-norm, say for example the maximal $C^*$-norm, may happen to disagree with restricting a $C^*$-norm. It is an actually very important theorem that the restriction of the universally defined spatial $C^*$-norm agrees with restricting the spatial $C^*$-norm.

Comment: furthermore, you can check II.9.6.2 in Blackadars book "Theory of $C^*$-Algebras and von Neumann Algebras"

Comment: @FreeziiS no, convince yourself this is here not the case and that for ideals everything works fine

Comment: Ah great, thanks the reference!!!! :D

Comment: @FreeziiS thank you for having a critical view on my attempts:), in theses cases I always learn something new as well. However, you are right and I was not aware that there this is an issue for general $C^*$-subalgebras ( there is a discussion about this in Brown-Ozawas book, corollary 3.6.4)

Comment: @SabrinaGemsa: You're welcome! :) I learned this issue from https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/1655, the paragraph starting with "The spatial $C^*$-norm has several good properties, ..." By the way, thanks also for the Brown-Ozawa reference, it seems very nicely readable. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion (I hope that nothing is wrong):

Let $$F:B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\to B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{min} B(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$$ be the canonical map and define $M:=\ker(F)$. Since $F$ is not injective, $M$ is nontrivial.

Claim: $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N})) \cap M = 0$.

First note that $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$ is nuclear (because it's a inductive limit of nuclear $C^*$-algebras) and simple, therefore $$K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\cong K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{min} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$$ is simple.
It follows 
$K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N})) \cap M=\ker(F_{|K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))})=0$, because $F_{|K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))}$ is nonzero and $\ker(F_{|K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))})$ is an ideal in $K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))\otimes_{max} K(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$.